# travis gitflow java maven workflow

Tags: maven, travis-ci, git-flow, sonatype

I all,

working on a java project hosted on github.
I would like to push the code directly to sonatype on development and master branch.

currently only the **develop** branch works because I skipped the gpg signing

I use the **setting.xml** in .travis folder with my credentials

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <!-- Maven Central Deployment -->
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <username>${env.SONATYPE_USERNAME}</username>
            <password>${env.SONATYPE_PASSWORD}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <gpg.executable>gpg</gpg.executable>
                <gpg.passphrase>${env.GPG_PASSPHRASE}</gpg.passphrase>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

my **travis.yml** looks like this:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

script:
 - mvn --settings .travis/settings.xml clean verify

deploy:
 -
  provider: script
  script:
   - mvn --settings .travis/settings.xml deploy -D gpg.skip -P release
  on:
    branch: develop
 -
  provider: script
  script:
   - mvn --settings .travis/settings.xml org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.3:set -D newVersion=$TRAVIS_TAG -P release
   - .travis/gpg.sh
   - mvn clean deploy --settings .travis/settings.xml -D skipTests=true --batch-mode --update-snapshots -P release
  on:
    tags: true
```

my release profile include the deploy plugins needed.

I am getting an error when I push a tag/release (like 0.0.2). I expect this to deploy a release using the tag.

The develop branch works fine and the snapshot is deployed to sonatype repo correctly.

https://github.com/effectus-io/effectus-parent

thanks in advance

here is the travis log error.

`` The command "mvn --settings .travis/settings.xml clean verify" exited with 0.
Skipping a deployment with the script provider because this branch is not permitted
dpl.0
Fetching: dpl-1.8.31.gem (100%)Fetching: dpl-1.8.31.gem (100%)
Successfully installed dpl-1.8.31
1 gem installed
dpl.1
Installing deploy dependencies
!!! Script support is experimental !!!
Preparing deploy
Cleaning up git repository with `git stash --all`. If you need build artifacts for deployment, set `deploy.skip_cleanup: true`. See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#Uploading-Files.
No local changes to save
dpl.3
Deploying application
No stash found.
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.31/lib/dpl/cli.rb:54:in `system': wrong first argument (ArgumentError)
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.31/lib/dpl/cli.rb:54:in `shell'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.31/lib/dpl/provider/script.rb:18:in `push_app'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.31/lib/dpl/provider.rb:146:in `block in deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.31/lib/dpl/cli.rb:41:in `fold'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.31/lib/dpl/provider.rb:146:in `deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.31/lib/dpl/cli.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.31/lib/dpl/cli.rb:7:in `run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.31/bin/dpl:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/dpl:23:in `load'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/dpl:23:in `<main>'
failed to deploy ``

Comment: Not entirely sure how to help you, but browsing DPL I did see this: https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/pull/466 , you might take a look there and see if any of the commits give you clues on how to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

after much trial and error I realised it is just too much work to try and sign release on travis, there is no good support and that is a shame.

My alternative solution is to use bintray -> https://bintray.com/
it provides a release repo with automate gpg signing of the jars. It also sync with sonatype so I believe this is a complete solution using maven.

in the pom I automated the versioning with the plugin -> https://github.com/effectus-io/effectus-parent/blob/master/pom.xml#L299
notice I do not commit from travis!

I kept the snapshot going directly into sonatype for simplicity ->https://github.com/effectus-io/effectus-parent/blob/master/.travis.yml#L34

you can see my workflow here -> https://github.com/effectus-io/effectus-parent/releases/tag/0.0.10

using gitflow, normal commit to develop branch will automatically push a snapshot to sonatype. Using a release (after tagging) will trigger a build and reversioning using the maven version plugin wich will remove the SNAPSHOT from the pom(s) and deploy to bintray.

Comment: To avoid the set version thing, one could do `<version>${revision}<version>`, see here: https://axelfontaine.com/blog/dead-burried.html
For travis I followed: https://dracoblue.net/dev/uploading-snapshots-and-releases-to-maven-central-with-travis/ the only important thing was to store the GPG related env variables without newline e.g. `gpg --export-ownertrust | base64 | tr -d '\n'`